# How to display the SharePoint "Live Persona Card"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

In our SharePoint Framework web parts we want to show people information just like SharePoint does:

[image: live persona card]

When hovering over the name or image of somebody a popup like this should open.
Looking at the source this thing seems to go by the moniker "Live Persona Card":

[image: live parsona card source code]

Searching for `LivePersonaCard` yields few results. One is a [blog post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52249.sharepoint-online-live-persona-card-in-custom-webpart.aspx) describing how to load and include this standard component via `SPComponentLoader` and some [hard-coded IDs](https://github.com/Anil-Lakhagoudar/SPFxLivePersonaCard/blob/c4696234852850a4db201c664d420067bb43048d/src/webparts/spContactCard/components/SPFXPeopleCard/SPFxPeopleCard.tsx#L30).

Since information is rare on this subject my question is: is this the way to go? Or is there an alternative component we should use, like from PnP oder Office UI Fabric (doesn't seem so)?

Answer (score 2):

Heinrich,

In my past projects, I have created my own persona card using the Office UI Fabric control:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js/components/personacard/personacard

Unfortunately, it doesn't do the work for you -- you need to retrieve the data and populate the card.

I like the idea of a PnP control though... if you make the suggestion I'd be happy to volunteer to implement it.

I hope this helps?

Comment: I created a new suggestion on the PnP repo, feel free to comment:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues/259

Comment: Fine with me :)

Comment: @HugoBernier - Do you know of a working sample that's populating the Office UI Fabric PersonaCard control with data from the MSGraph API?  Seems like the OrgChart would be the toughest part...

Comment: @tracy, take a look at this awesome sample https://www.github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples%2Freact-modern-organization-chart. You can also borrow the code from my pull request (see above). I hope it helps?