# Open immersive popup

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

Anyone having idea on how to open the immersive popup with contact in a Web Part, like when we have a person in a grid a have a mouse hover?

I'm using SharePoint online tenant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is profile cards in Office 365. You can use People web part which allows you to call the profile cards when hovering over a user.

You can also use SharePoint Framework web parts to display profile cards.

Please see the references below.

[Profile cards in Office 365.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/profile-cards-in-office-365-e80f931f-5fc4-4a59-ba6e-c1e35a85b501)

[Show people profiles on your page with the People web part.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-people-profiles-on-your-page-with-the-people-web-part-7e52c5f6-2d72-48fa-a9d3-d2750765fa05)

[How to display the SharePoint “Live Persona Card”?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/259908/how-to-display-the-sharepoint-live-persona-card)